# Replacing the `k`-th row of a matrix with zero in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I want to ask about using a temporary variable to replace the `k`-th row of matrix.

I would like a row of `X` to be replaced by zero.

So, I have created a copy of `X` called `Ynew1`, and in every iteration the value of `Ynew1` is updated by `X` (first value). But, in my code, not only are the rows of `Ynew1` replaced by 0, but the `X` too. Unfortunately, the result is `Ynew1` is matrix all zero (I expected the result just last row has zero value). this is the code :

```
cppFunction('
            NumericMatrix cobo(NumericMatrix X){
            int n = X.nrow();
            NumericMatrix Ynew1(n,1);

            for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
              Ynew1 = X;
              for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    Ynew1(k,i)=0;
              }
            }

            return(Ynew1);
            }
            ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I think the objective you are trying to accomplish is the following:

> replace the `k`-th row of `x` by zero

The for-loop structure you are using is not ideal. At each `i` or row iteration you are re-copying `x` to `Ynew` and then proceeding to zero out the row.

In this case, you just should be targeting the `k`-th row like so:

```
cppFunction('
// @param x A \code{matrix} with dimensions n x m. 
// @param k An \code{unsigned int} whose index begins at 1.
// @return A \code{matrix} with row \code{k} equal to zero.
Rcpp::NumericMatrix cobo(Rcpp::NumericMatrix x, unsigned int k){
  unsigned int n = x.nrow();

  // Bounds check
  if(k - 1 >= n){ stop("OOB Error"); }

  // Replace row by a vector of zeros.
  x(k - 1, Rcpp::_) = Rcpp::NumericVector(x.ncol());

  return x;
}
')
```

Note: The function handles R matrix input. (e.g. assumes index starts at 1 and not C++'s 0.)

Example:

```
set.seed(11) # Set seed for reproducibility
(x = matrix(rnorm(10),nrow = 5))

            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.59103110 -0.93415132
[2,]  0.02659437  1.32360565
[3,] -1.51655310  0.62491779
[4,] -1.36265335 -0.04572296
[5,]  1.17848916 -1.00412058

cobo(x, 3)

            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.59103110 -0.93415132
[2,]  0.02659437  1.32360565
[3,]  0.00000000  0.00000000
[4,] -1.36265335 -0.04572296
[5,]  1.17848916 -1.00412058
```